# twitter bootstrap overlapping borders of items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter-bootstrap-2.0.4

```
...some topbar code here....
div.container-fluid
  div.content
    div.row-fluid
      div.span2
        div.menuLeft
          a(class='menuLeftItem', href="http://localhost:3000") Explore
          br/
          a(class='menuLeftItem', href="http://localhost:3000") My Playlists
          br/
          a(class='menuLeftItem', href="http://localhost:3000") Challenge
          br/
          a(class='menuLeftItem', href="http://localhost:3000") Socialize
          br/
```

My CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding:0; }

html, body {
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  padding-top: 58px; /* 40px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.container-fluid {
  background-color: black;
}
.content {
  background-color: blue;
}
.span2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.menuLeftItem {
  color:white;
  /*font*/
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:1;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

My menuLeftItems are not aligned properly. Specifically the borders of those elements are overlapping. Please tell me how to properly align the elements. Also I want to each menuLeftItem to take the same width as its containing element span2. I tried width = 100% for .menuLeftItem. But it does not take effect.

My goal is to create a fixed page layout for different screen sizes. Hence I am trying to used fluid layouts.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How can I increase the width of element "a" of class menuLeftItem above? Nothing seems to take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Fixed it. I needed to add display: inline-block to the class menuLeftItem. I found this as reference on another stack thread
[HTML/CSS - Extend element width to visible area (beyond width of containing element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936973/html-css-extend-element-width-to-visible-area-beyond-width-of-containing-elem)